# Voice-to-text on keyboard in HTC Sense

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-sense, voice-command

I've just got my phone upgraded to Android 2.1. It's a HTC Hero running HTC Sense. One of the features I was really looking forward to in Android 2.1 was the microphone button on the keyboard which you can use to dictate into any text field.

However, this button doesn't seem to be there on the HTC Sense keyboard. Is there any way to enable this?

Comment: So did you try anything?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings, Language and Keyboard and see if there is another keyboard you can enable and use. If there is one, check the box to enable it. Then go out and open something that requires text input like an text message. Long click on the text field and choose Input Method. Then change to the keyboard you just enabled. See if it has the microphone.

If you only have one keyboard to enable you could try a third party one like Swiftkey Beta. I use it and it has a microphone option for speech input. Plus the keyboard rocks with all kinds of great features.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to download this keyboard, and it has a microphone button.

Comment: Would you mind voting?

Answer (score 1):

The new OTA update of Android version **2.10.405.2** included a voice-to-text option on the keyboard. The *microphone* key is located on the left of the *comma* key.

[image: SMS window]

NB: I believe this update has only so far been released to unlocked HTC phone users only... if your phone is locked to a network you must wait for your network to push the update.